# Including Ghostscript when creating .msi with cx_freeze

Tags: python, ghostscript, cx-freeze

I have a Dash app which uses Camelot in lattice mode and this needs Ghostscript to run. I know that using stream removes the need for Ghostscript, but I lattice works best for my use case.

I'm using cx_freeze to create a .msi that users can install. **How can I include Ghostscript in the .msi file?**

Without Ghostscript, users are getting this error - `RuntimeError: Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed`

I've tried including the Ghostscript folder in "include files" in setup.py, but the users are still getting the same error.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this in the end?